# Remove Proceed to checkout button on Cart page for specific items based on shipping country

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, countries

We have categories for in-house products that only ship to US and CA, and also have POD categories that ship internationally. I modified the code from [Set specific Products to be shipped only in specific countries in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756521/set-specific-products-to-be-shipped-only-in-specific-countries-in-woocommerce?rq=3&answertab=trending#tab-top) .

I want to display a notice/warning and disable checkout in cart page unless the customer, from outside the US and CA, delete the in-house products in the cart.

I added 2 lines of code in the first function. They didn't work as expected. The notice shows up everywhere and multiple times in Cart. The checkout button is not disabled. How can I modify this?

My code:

```
function your_country_shipping_settings(){
    $results = array();
    // Can be based on "Product IDs" (or "Product categories" ==> false)
    $results['type'] = false; // or false

    // Allowed countries (Only compatible country codes - 2 digits)
    $results['countries'] = array( 'US', 'CA' );

    if( $results['type'] ){
        // Restricted product IDs
        $results['matching'] = array( 37, 38 );
    } else {
        // Restricted product categories (IDs, Slugs or Names)
       $results['matching'] = array('t-shirts', 'sweet-shirts' );
         
    }
    // Message
    $results['message'] = __( "can not be delivered to your country.", "woocommerce" );
    //added by me, disable checkout 
     wc_add_notice( __( "This product is shipping to US address only.", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    return $results;
}

// Utility function that check cart items
function get_items_names( $matching, $package, $type ){
    $product_names = array();

    // Search in cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        if( $type ){
            if( in_array( $item['data']->get_id(), $matching ) )
                $product_names[] = $item['data']->get_name();
        } else {
            if( has_term( $matching, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) )
                $product_names[] = $item['data']->get_name();
        }
    }
    return $product_names;
}

// Conditionally disabling shipping methods
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','custom_country_shipping_rules', 10, 2 );
function custom_country_shipping_rules( $rates, $package ){
    if( isset($package['destination']['country']) && isset($package['contents']) ){
        // Load your settings
        $data = your_country_shipping_settings();

        // If matching allowed countries ==> We Exit
        if( in_array( $package['destination']['country'], $data['countries'] ) )
            return $rates; // Exit

        $product_names = get_items_names( $data['matching'], $package, $data['type'] );

        // When product match we Remove all shipping methods
        if( count($product_names) > 0 ){
            // Removing all shipping methods
            foreach( $rates as $rate_id => $rate )
                unset( $rates[$rate_id] );
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Conditionally displaying a shipping message
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html','custom_country_shipping_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter('woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html','custom_country_shipping_notice', 10, 1 );
function custom_country_shipping_notice( $html ){
    $package = WC()->shipping->get_packages()[0];
    if( isset($package['destination']['country']) && isset($package['contents']) ){
        // Load your settings
        $data = your_country_shipping_settings();

        // If matching allowed countries ==> We Exit
        if( in_array( $package['destination']['country'], $data['countries'] ) )
            return $html; // Exit

        $product_names = get_items_names( $data['matching'], $package, $data['type'] );

        if( count($product_names) > 0 ){
            $text = '"' . implode( '", "', $product_names ) . '" ' . $data['message'];
            $html  = wpautop( $text );
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

The in-house products might ship outside the US and CA in the future, so I don't want to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove your changes *(from first function)*:

```php
//added by me, disable checkout 
     wc_add_notice( __( "This product is shipping to US address only.", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
```

Then add the following hooked function to your code *(updated to handle checkout page)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'disable_checkout_submit_button' );
function disable_checkout_submit_button() {
    $package = WC()->shipping->get_packages()[0];
    if( isset($package['destination']['country']) && isset($package['contents']) ){
        // Load your settings
        $data = your_country_shipping_settings();

        // If matching allowed countries ==> We Exit
        if( in_array( $package['destination']['country'], $data['countries'] ) )
            return; // Exit

        $product_names = get_items_names( $data['matching'], $package, $data['type'] );

        if( count($product_names) > 0 ){
            if ( is_cart() ) {
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
            } elseif ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
                add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'disabled_place_order_button_html');
            }
            wc_clear_notices();
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Some products are shipping to US And Canada exclusively.', 'woocommerce' ), "error" );
        }
    }
}

function disabled_place_order_button_html() {
    $order_button_text = __('Place order', 'woocommerce');
    echo '<button type="button" class="button alt disabled" id="place_order_disabled">' . $order_button_text . '</button>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The warning notice works perfectly. however the checkout button is not disabled. Either with "can not be delivered to your country. Enter a different address" or with "Enter your address to view shipping options. Calculate shipping" situation, the checkout button leads to checkout page, with or without POD products in cart.

Comment: If the "Proceed to checkout" button is not removed in cart page, is related to your theme, as it works perfectly on WooCommerce Storefront theme and in WordPress Base themes…

Comment: You are absolutely correct.   I tested it on 2022 theme and it blocked "place order". I am using Astra theme......Is there any way to work around it? Any suggestions？

Comment: I have uploaded Astra theme (free), and enable it… The code works too in Astra. So I really don't know where your issue is coming from, it could be some other customizations that you did and interact…

Comment: In fact, the"Proceed to checkout" button can lead to “place order" in all themes.  I didn't scrolled down enough to see the button at the bottom.  I didn't try if the order coulld go through. This is a simple site with free Astra theme and plugins, and with some code for tweaks. POD overrides some settings in Woocommerce. Here is the "place order" page in 2022 theme.  https://snipboard.io/zMsKSt.jpg

Comment: This code is not for checkout "place order" button, but for **cart page "proceed to checkout" button** (check your question and your related added code).

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. My initial assumption was that if the "proceed to checkout" button were successfully disabled on the cart page with a specific item in the cart, the subsequent "checkout" page would not appear. I used to think that it worked with 2022 theme, that's why I share the "checkout" page to confirm that it didn't.